# error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined,, trying to push element to object

Tags: node.js

```
const fs=require('fs')

function add(task1){

    var notes=loadNotes()
    notes.push({
        task:task1
    })
    saveItems(notes)
}

function saveItems(notes)
{

     dataJSON=JSON.stringify(notes)
     fs.writeFileSync('notes.json',dataJSON)
}

function loadNotes()
{

    try{
        data=fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        dataBuffer=data.toString()
        finalData=JSON.parse(dataBuffer)
        console.log(finalData)
    }
    catch(e)
    {   
        console.log('emptyList')
        return []
    }
}
module.exports={
    add: add
}
```

Comment: you will need to return the something in `loadNotes()`

Comment: Solved thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function "loadNotes" is not returning the list of notes.

```
function loadNotes()
{

  try{
    data=fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
    dataBuffer=data.toString()
    finalData=JSON.parse(dataBuffer)
    console.log(finalData)
    return finalData;
}
catch(e)
  {   
    console.log('emptyList')
    return []
  }
}
```